# How to Pass Value from Control to View Json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC. Here is my code, I'm looking for expert help.

In this code i am calculating SaleTotal

```
[HttpPost]
public double SaleTotal(DateTime? FromDate, DateTime? ToDate)
{
    var Sales = from s in db.SalesMasters
                where (s.BillDate >= FromDate && s.BillDate <= ToDate)
                select s.STotal;

    var SalesReturn = from s in db.SReturnMasters
                      where s.ReturnDate >= FromDate && s.ReturnDate <= ToDate
                      select s.SRTotal;

    double  TotalSales = Sales.Sum().GetValueOrDefault();
    double TotalSalesReturn = SalesReturn.Sum().GetValueOrDefault();

    double Balance = TotalSales - TotalSalesReturn;

    return Balance;
}

public ActionResult AllSaleReport(JQueryDataTableParamModel param, int? BillNo , DateTime ? FromDate,DateTime? ToDate)
{
    double SalesTotal=SaleTotal(FromDate, ToDate);                              

    var Sales = (from S in db.SalesMasters
                 where (S.BillDate >= FromDate && S.BillDate <= ToDate )
                          select S).ToList();

       var filteredSales=(from S in db.SalesMasters
                 where (S.BillDate >= FromDate && S.BillDate <= ToDate &&       S.CancelFlag==false )
                          select S).ToList();

                 var result = from S in filteredSales.Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength)
                 select new[] { S.BillDate.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), Convert.ToString(S.BillNo), S.RefName, S.Paymode, Convert.ToString(S.NetAmt) };

    return Json(new
    {
        sEcho = param.sEcho,
        iTotalRecords = Sales.Count,
        iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredSales.Count,
        aaData = result,
        SalesReturn = SaleTotal(FromDate, ToDate)
    },
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My JavaScript to load data to DataTable

```
function LoadAllData() {

var reportTable = $('#AllSales').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        //"bprocessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": false,
       "bServerSide": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        //"bAutoWidth": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,
        //"sProcessing": "<img src=~/Content/images/ajax-loader.gif />",
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "sSwfPath": "~/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "fnPreDrawCallback": function () {
            $("#AllSales").hide();
            $("#loading").show();
            // alert("Pre Draw");
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            $("#AllSales").show();
            $("#loading").hide();
            // alert("Draw");
        },
        "fnInitComplete": function () {

        },
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "FromDate", "value": $("#FromDate").val() })
            aoData.push({ "name": "ToDate", "value": $("#ToDate").val() })
        },
        "sAjaxSource": "/Report/AllSaleReport",

        "footerCallback": function (row, aoData, start, end, display) {
            var api = this.api(), aoData;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function (i) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            data = api.column(4).data();
            alert(data.length);
           // alert(SalesReturn);
            total = data.length ?
                data.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);                    
                }) :
                0;

            // Total over this page
            data = api.column(4, { page: 'current' }).data();

            pageTotal = data.length ?
                data.reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }) :
                0;

            // Update footer
            $(api.column(4).footer()).html(
                '$' + pageTotal + ' ( $' + total + ' total)'
            );
        }
    });
  };
```

I want to pass SaleTotal to DataTable or my View

How can I Pass SaleTotal from controller to view. I tried many ways but still my problem not solved.

Comment: Could you describe what errors you get?

Comment: And how does the json look when you call /Report/AllSaleReport ?

Comment: need to add saleTotal in footer of DataTable..

Comment: SaleReport is Working fine..but i cant pass the SaleTotal from Control to View

Comment: But you do have that data in your json result when you call /Report/AllSaleReport. Right? That's why I asked how the json looked. Then you can grab that data and insert it where you want.

Comment: but i dont know how to grab saleTotal to My datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly the data you want is the data from the SaleTotal method.

That data is in the json returned from the AllSaleReport method:

```
return Json(new
{
    ...
    SalesReturn = SaleTotal(FromDate, ToDate)
},
```

So when you call the AllSaleReport from DataTable use [fnServerData](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) to override the function that gets that data and insert it where you want it. Something like:

```
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (result) {
                var saleTotal = result.SalesReturn;

                // Insert saleTotal in footer

                fnCallback(result);

        });
    },
```